# Windows and States in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**This first question;**

I want to learn time behaviour of window. Let's assume I'll process data every 2 seconds with the `Processing time`, and the current time is `10:26:25.169`. At this time, I deployed job.

In this case, Will each time window be rounded to 0, 2, 4 and so on seconds? Like below;

- `10:26:24.000 - 10:26:26.000`
- `10:26:26.000 - 10:26:28.000`

As you can see, i've deploy job at `10:26:25.169`, but flink did round window by 2 seconds. Is that right?

If not, Does windows works like below?;

- `10:26:25.169 - 10:26:27.169`
- `10:26:27.169 - 10:26:29.169`

Which one is true? Is this behaviour can change when I use `event time` instead of `processing time`?

**The second question;**

I want to keep state for each key. For that i can use richFlatMap function or keyedProcessFunction. But i wonder that can I manage state using above functions after applied window? For example;

```
// in this case i can manage state by key
ds.keyBy(_.field).process(new MyStateFunction)

// in this case, can i manage state after window for the same key? 
ds.keyBy(keyExtractorWithTime)
  .window(new MyWindowFunction)
  .reduce(new myRedisFunction)
  .process(new MyStateFunction)
```

Comment: This, and other quirks of the window API, is covered in a tutorial in the docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/streaming_analytics.html#surprises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, it will always be full 2 second interval rounded, so basically as You've described:

```
10:26:24.000 - 10:26:26.000
10:26:26.000 - 10:26:28.000
```

There is an `offset` argument that allows You to control that behaviour to some extent. But basically while the Flink actually creates the window when the data arrives, the `startTime` and `endTime` do not depend on when the data arrives, so the data is fit into the window not the other way around.

More info can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html)

As, for the second question the `ProcessWindowFunction` is keyed function and thus You will be able to use keyed state inside the function just as You would be able to do it in standard `ProcessFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**: If `offset` parameter not be assigned, flink will use integer multiples of window size as the `startTime` by default (`endTime` = `startTime` + `windowSize`). So the blow you asked is right.

```
10:26:24.000 - 10:26:26.000
10:26:26.000 - 10:26:28.000
```

In flink, the `startTime` will be calculated by this way:

```
/**
  * Method to get the window start for a timestamp.
  *
  * @param timestamp epoch millisecond to get the window start.
  * @param offset The offset which window start would be shifted by.
  * @param windowSize The size of the generated windows. windowSize.
  * @return window start
*/
public static long getWindowStartWithOffset(long timestamp, long offset, long windowSize) {
    return timestamp - (timestamp - offset + windowSize) % windowSize;
}
```

**Question 2**: If you want manage state after Keyed Window, the below way maybe effective. This way allow you manage the state and `reduce` function results for each window.

```
DataStream<SensorReading> input = ...;

input
  .keyBy(<key selector>)
  .timeWindow(<duration>)
  .reduce(new MyReduceFunction(), new MyProcessWindowFunction());

// Function definitions

private static class MyReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<SensorReading> {

  public SensorReading reduce(SensorReading r1, SensorReading r2) {
      return r1.value() > r2.value() ? r2 : r1;
  }
}

private static class MyProcessWindowFunction
    extends ProcessWindowFunction<SensorReading, Tuple2<Long, SensorReading>, String, TimeWindow> {

  public void process(String key,
                    Context context,
                    Iterable<SensorReading> minReadings,
                    Collector<Tuple2<Long, SensorReading>> out) {
      SensorReading min = minReadings.iterator().next();
      out.collect(new Tuple2<Long, SensorReading>(context.window().getStart(), min));
  }
}
```

For more detail [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction-with-incremental-aggregation).